# Does the Webpack "Resolve" feature resolve AMD style path definitions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amd, webpack

I'm trying to get a very simple proof of concept working here... I have a js lib that uses AMD, but I need the dependencies to resolve to node_modules.  So I have the following:

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./resources/content/scripts/twitter_module",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "out.js",
  },
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    modulesDirectories: [ path.join(__dirname, "node_modules") ]
  }
};
```

This is the output I get from webpack:

```
Hash: bab530b56faec6755978
Version: webpack 1.8.2
Time: 49ms
 Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
out.js  8.6 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./resources/content/scripts/twitter_module.js 6.44 kB {0} [built] [3 errors]

ERROR in ./resources/content/scripts/twitter_module.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'vendor.asset.jquery/jquery' in /Users/bob/projects/repository/resources/content/scripts
 @ ./resources/content/scripts/twitter_module.js 3:0-198:2

ERROR in ./resources/content/scripts/twitter_module.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'vendor.asset.jquery/jquery.ie.cors' in /Users/bob/projects/repository/resources/content/scripts
 @ ./resources/content/scripts/twitter_module.js 3:0-198:2

ERROR in ./resources/content/scripts/twitter_module.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'vendor.asset.moment/moment' in /Users/bob/projects/repository/resources/content/scripts
 @ ./resources/content/scripts/twitter_module.js 3:0-198:2
```

The output suggests that the resolve config isn't being used/applied.  It's still looking for scripts in the same directory of the module that's trying to import them.  Does resolve only work for common.js requires?  Every thing in the docs and examples I've read seems to suggest that this should work.

Including Directory Structure:

```
➜  repository  pwd
/Users/bob/projects/repository

➜  repository  ls resources/content/scripts/twitter_module.js
resources/content/scripts/twitter_module.js
```

external dependencies exist in these vendor packages:

```
➜  repository  ls vendor.asset.jquery/content/scripts/jquery.js
vendor.asset.moment/content/scripts/jquery.js

➜  repository  ls vendor.asset.moment/content/scripts/moment.js
vendor.asset.moment/content/scripts/moment.js
```

Comment: Please add your project file/folder structure.

Comment: added some dir path references.  I'm actually not trying to to resolve to node_modules, I just figured it would be easier to explain.  I'm expecting the paths I define in the resolve config to show in the webpack output

Comment: Do you have a server which is serving your files or do you open your via `file:///`?

Comment: Right now I'm not thinking about the web server or serving these files, I just want to define an entry script in webpack and have it compile that script along with all of it's dependencies.  All of my directory references are just standard unix paths.  It seems this is not a problem if you are using common.js requires, but my libs all use AMD definitions, which webpack is supposed to support.

Comment: Check paths relative to path where script runs and see if it resolves to required files. The error messages are clear: `repository/resources/content/scripts` can't find file `./resources/content/scripts/twitter_module.js`. Try if changing the latter to just `./twitter_module.js` fixes it. Obviously, you have to fix path like that for every error.

Comment: That's precisely the problem, all of my code is broken up into modules, hundreds of them.  When a module imports another module in the define statement, webpack looks for the dependency in the current module's directory- I would never have a use case for this behavior.  I can't change the directory structure, it's a pattern that hundreds of developers I work with use.  I thought by setting the resolve root or modulesDirectories, webpack would look in alternate locations for the dependencies.

Comment: You need to have the files accessible by webpack, therefore when using a server, the required dependancies also have to be served. Then webpack will be able to access these files. It's hard for me to know how to fix things without knowing exactly how you're trying to do it, what's your folder structure etc.

Comment: I created a simplified repo with the directory structure that supports both amd and commonjs examples and they actually all work fine. So I guess have to do some more digging to see why I'm having problems with my existing repository.  Thanks for the suggestions, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem I'm having is that it appears the Webpack log output is a bit misleading.  When you have multiple "resolve" locations, it seems webpack only reports the current directory as the location of the missing dependencies despite searching other paths and having root paths defined in the resolve config.  If you have a pathing problem that is in, say, your root resolve path, webpack does not indicate that it tried to look there.